# How to label Highcharts x-axis depending on number of points

Tags: javascript, graph, formatting, highcharts

I want to get the length of the xAxis array for the visible series so that my x-axis can have a relative label. Think 'x Days Ago'.

When all my lines had 31 points, I was fine with

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return 30 - this.value;
  }
}
```

but now my series have different numbers of points. I know there's the Chart.xAxis function, but I'm not sure how to get that value from inside the formatter. `return this.chart.xAxis.length - this.value` shows negative numbers starting with 1, so it appears to be returning 0. `return this.chart.xAxis[0].length` doesn't work either, which is the syntax if there were multiple x-axes.

My series data uses the hash format and each series starts with 0 as the first x-axis value.

So how do I get the length of the array of x-axis values for visible series?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from tickPositions array. 
http://jsfiddle.net/FbFC2/

```
chart.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length
```

Comment: That only works if the you have the same number of ticks as you have points, which isn't always true in my case. I was able to use `this.axis.dataMax`, but that only works cause my dataMax is the same as my number of points.